# What is the relevance of "the infant dropped the breast from his mouth" and from where is it derived?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, song-poetry, yam-suf

סוטה ל עמוד ב -----------------Sotah 30b

תנו רבנן דרש רבי יוסי הגלילי בשעה שעלו ישראל מן הים נתנו עיניהם לומר שירה וכיצד אמרו שירה **עולל מוטל על ברכי אמו ותינוק יונק משדי אמו** כיון שראו את השכינה **עולל הגביה צוארו ותינוק שמט דד מפיו** ואמרו זה אלי ואנוהו שנאמר (תהלים ח, ג) מפי עוללים **ויונקים** יסדת עוז**

§ The Sages taught in a baraita that Rabbi Yosei HaGelili taught: At the time that the Jewish people ascended from the sea they resolved to sing a song of gratitude to God. And how did they recite this song? If a baby was lying on his mother’s lap or an infant was nursing from his mother’s breasts, once they saw the Divine Presence, **the baby straightened his neck and the infant dropped the breast from his mouth,** and they recited: “This is my God and I will glorify Him” (Exodus 15:2). As it is stated: “Out of the mouths of babies and **sucklings** You have founded strength” (Psalms 8:3).

היה רבי מאיר אומר מנין שאפי' עוברים שבמעי אמן אמרו שירה שנאמר...

Rabbi Meir would say: From where is it derived that even fetuses in their mother’s womb recited the song at the sea? As it is stated...

RASHI: עולל - גדול מיונק

"BABY"- Is bigger than "suckling"...

It would seem that this Gemara is coming to tell us that all the Jews on all levels of maturity, even the babys the sucklings and the fetuses recited the *Shirah* at the sea.
If this is so, why is it necessary to tell us that *the infant dropped the breast from his mouth*? The whole point is that "sucklings", which refers to the age/ maturity level, as we see from Rashi, also recited *shirah*. The act of their suckling at the time doesn't seem relevant here.

The Gemara for some reason is translating the word יונקים- "sucklings" in the passuk as those who are actually doing the act of suckling, rather than those who are of suckling age.

Where is meaning this derived from the passuk, and what is it's relevance?

Comment: It seems to be about priorities. Developmentally, the suckling sees the nursing as an end-all. Comprehension of the "other" develops later. Even moreso, one would think, would be the understanding of God. And yet even the child, always focused on the self and the nursing, had such an awareness of hashem that he chose to stop nursing, a miraculous act. Usually, a distracted nurser keeps the latch on, much to the dismay of the mother.

Comment: @rosends Nice idea.Why didn't you put it in as an answer?

Comment: because it is something I made up. It has no basis in anything.

Comment: @rosends מה שתלמיד עתיד להורות כבר נאמר למשה בסיני - What a  student will teach in the future has already been  taught to Moshe at Sinai.